# Help with finding subsets that are divisible by $3^k$

Tags: number-theory

For positive integers $n$, let $v_3(n)$ denote the largest integer $k$ such that $3^k$ divides $n$. Find the number of subsets $S$ (possibly containing $0$ or $1$ elements) of $\{1, 2, \ldots ,81\}$ such that for any distinct $a, b \in S, v_3(a-b)$ is even.

So, I don't know how to start this problem, nor do I know what would consist of an answer - like what would a subset mean in this context? Any help with solving the problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't know it means for a subset to have $0$ or $1$ elements, or you don't understand why such subsets fulfill the condition?

Comment: I don't know what both means

Comment: It's just saying that the subset can indeed contain 0 or 1 elements, even though these are a rather trivial case.

Comment: yea I'm starting to get it now, but what would be a subset that fulfill the condition

Comment: The only subset with $0$ elements is the empty set.  The subsets with one element are $\{1\},\{2\}cdots,\{81\}$

Comment: You really ought to think about the problem more before posting a question here.  What are some $two-element$ subsets that fulfill the condition?  Wha are some that don't?

Comment: oh I see! Thank you! so basically you are looking for the subsets that are divisible by 9 (k =2) and divisible by 1 (k=0)

Comment: wait could you explain why 1,2 and 81 are the subsets with one element? what would "b" then be? what are you subtracting?

Comment: When @saul wrote $cdots$ he meant $\cdots$ but it really should have been $\dots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set with $0$ elements is an *empty* set, it is, a set with no elements. The empty set is usually denoted by $\emptyset$.

A set with $1$ element is a set of the form $\{a\}$ with $a$ being its only element. This kind of set is usally called a *singleton*.

---

Let's find which numbers $n$ have $v_3(n)$ even, and then you just has to express $n=a-b$ for $a,b\in S$. $v_3(n)$ even means that $n$ is divisible by one of the following (and not divisible by any larger power of $3$): $1$, $9$, $81$.

Every number is divisible by $1$, but you have to find those which are not divisible by any larger power of $3$. Here you've got $1$, $2$, $4$, $5$,... In general, the numbers of the form $1+3k$ or $2+3k$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ small enough no stay in $\{0,1,\dots, 81\}$.
 Hence, you have the subsets $\{a,b\in \{0,1,\dots, 81\}: a\neq b,a-b=1+3k\}$ and $\{a,b\in \{0,1,\dots, 81\}: a\neq b,a-b=2+3k\}$.

Another way to write it, if you are familiar with congruences is $a-b\equiv 1\mod 3$ and $a-b\equiv 2\mod 3$ respectively.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you explain how to find the singleton sets, and what they mean conceptually?  And yes I can continue... thank you again!

Comment: The question says that possibly there are singletons, but it's not sure, you'll have to find the sets and then figure out if there is more than one element.

Comment: In fact, I would say that in this case it makes no sense to have singletons, since you're requiring $a$ and $b$ to be distinct. If $a\neq b$, then $\{b\}\neq\{a,b\}\neq\{a\}$. The only way to have a singleton in this case is that $a=b$, since a set is the same if you write the an element several times, I mean $\{a,a\}=\{a\}$.

Comment: yea that makes sense

Comment: so would I just plug k =0, k=1.... k=27 and keep testing a and b values that work? are there any short cuts?

Comment: Instead of testing $a$ and $b$. You can fix $b$ and compute $a$ for each $k$.

Comment: It is sufficient to fix $b=1$ and $b=2$, since for larger $b$ you'll get the same values for $a$ except for the smaller ones.

Comment: I'm getting 2511 subsets, does that sound too high? Oh forgot about singletons, so would every number 1-81 count toward it's own set?

Comment: Probably not, I haven't done it myself, but it's not that huge compared to the total amount of subsets ($2^{81}$). I don't understad, do you mean if the set $\{1,\dots 81\}$ is a subset of itself?

Comment: like since a singleton could be a=b, so {1},{2},..{81} could be singletons, correct?

Comment: They *are* singletons, since they are sets consisting in only one element. But it's not the same the number $1$ as the set $\{1\}$. You've got $1\in\{1\}$.

Comment: I know this is kind of old, but you help me solve it? I'm still stuck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74027/discussion-between-javi-and-mathkid225).