# How can I solve this find the digits problem more rigorously?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Adjoin to the digits $739$ three more digits so that the resulting number $739 \text{_ _ _}$ is divisible by $6, 7, 8$, and $9$.

I can do some quick guess and check as well as some little tricks with $9$, $7$, $6$, and $8$ to arrive to an answer, but how could I show this with more rigor (like more concrete number theory)?

Answers: $739368$ and $739872$

Comment: Are you familiar with modular arithmetic ?

Comment: yea but how could I set up the equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, some quick eliminating.

If a number is divisible by $9$ and $8$ then it is divisible by $3$ and $2$ and therefore $6$.  So we don't have to worry about $6$.  If we can find a number that is divisible by $8$ and $9$, it will be divisible by $6$.

$8|1000$ so $8$ divides $739000$ so we just have to find $abc$ to be divisible by $8$.

Using the "sum of digits have same remainder with divided by $9$".  $739000 \equiv 7+ 3 + 9 \equiv 1 \mod 8$.  So $739000 + abc \equiv 1 + abc \mod 9$.

So we need $abc \equiv -1 \equiv 8 \mod 9$.

And $739000 \equiv 7000000 + 39000 \mod 7 \equiv 35000 +4000 \mod 7 \equiv 3500 + 500 \equiv 490 +  10 \equiv 7 + 3\equiv 3 \mod 7$.   So  $739000 + abc\equiv 3 + abc \mod 7$. So we need $abc \equiv - 3 \equiv 4 \mod 7$.

So we need $abc \equiv 0 \mod 8$ and $abc \equiv 4 \mod 7$ and $abc \equiv 8 \mod 9$.

We can use the chinese remainder theorem.

To get $abc \equiv 4 \mod 7$ and $abc \equiv 0 \mod 8$ we must find $m = 0 + 8k = 4 + 7j \mod 7*8$.  By trial (trial being comparing $4,11,18,25,32,39,46,53$ to $0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48$) and error (error being $4,11,18,25,39,46,53,0, 8, 16, 24, 40, 48$ don't work) we find that $32$ is the correct answer.

By chinese remainder theorem $abc \equiv 32 \mod 56$ is the only solution mod $56$.

Bear with me:  $56 \equiv 2 \mod 9$ (by the "sum of digits of a multiple of $9$ is a multiple of $9$") and $32 \equiv 5 \mod 9$ (ditto) so $32 +k*56 \equiv 5 + k*2 \mod 9$.  So $32 + 6*56 = 368\equiv 8 \mod 9$ and $368$  is a) divisible by $8$, b) has remainder $4$ when divided by $7$ and c) has remainder $8$ when divided by $9$.

To find other numbers where this is true we must add $7*8*9 = 504$.

So the two numbers are $739368$ and $739872$

Comment: hey, thanks again fleablood for a wonderful solution! Yea I got the set up part, just solving a system of modular equations is kinda tough, but your solution makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Let indicate

$$n=739xyz=7\cdot10^5+3\cdot10^4+9\cdot10^3+x\cdot10^2+y\cdot10+z$$

and consider

- $n\equiv 0 \pmod 6 \implies 4+4x+4y+z\equiv 0 \pmod 6\implies 4x+4y+z=2+6k$
- $n\equiv 0 \pmod 7 \implies 3+2x+3y+z \equiv0 \pmod 7 \implies 2x+3y+z=4+7h$
- $n\equiv 0 \pmod 8\implies 4x+2y+z\equiv 0 \pmod 8 \implies 4x+2y+z=8s$
- $n\equiv 0 \pmod 9 \implies 1+x+y+z \equiv 0 \pmod 9\implies x+y+z=8+9t$

Comment: Yea I'm stuck here though, do I build a system of equations...? If so, how do I solve such system of modular equations?

Comment: @mathkid225 I haven't tried up to now, I have only given the set up, I will try later and I will update the answer!

Comment: $$0 \pmod{6}\equiv a_0 + 4a_1 + 4a_2 + 4$$
$$0 \pmod{7}\equiv a_0 + 3a_1 + 2a_2 + 3$$
$$0 \pmod{8}\equiv a_0 + 2a_1 + 4a_2 + 0$$
$$0 \pmod{9}\equiv a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + 1$$

Here is what I got

Comment: @mathkid225 Good work, I didn't check up to now but we aìcan say that from the last $a_0+a_1+a_2 \equiv -1 \pmod 9$ that is that  $a_0+a_1+a_2 =8$ or =17 or = 26. with similar observation I think that we can obtain the result since we have not many cases to consider.

Comment: hmm ok, so it's just some guess and check now

Comment: @mathkid225 In this way yes it is a guess and check but we are sure to find all the solutions. I don't know if there are more direct method for such system of modular equations.

Comment: ah yea, thats mostly what I'm having trouble with - also not exactly on topic but could you help me with this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675497/help-with-finding-subsets-that-are-divisible-by-3k
they put it on hold, I edited it, but nothing has happened ://

Here is the chat for ithttps://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74027/discussion-between-javi-and-mathkid225

Answer (score 1):

Let the number be $[739ABC]$.

$$\begin{array}
&\hline
&  &739000&[ABC]&[739ABC]&\text{Remarks}\\
\hline
\mod 9 && 1 &8 & 0& A+B+C=9z+8=8,17,26&\cdots (1)\\
\mod 8 && 0 & 0 & 0& [ABC]=8n&\cdots (2)\\
\mod 7 && 3 & 4 & 0&[ABC]=7m+4&\cdots (3)\\
\hline
& & & & &(m,n,z\in\mathbb Z; A+B+C<27)\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Divisibility by $8$ and $9$ also ensures by $6$, so no need to check further.

Working through$^*$ the above gives
$$[ABC]=368\;\text{or}\; 872$$

---

*More details

Combining $(2),(3)$ gives $7m=8n-4=4(2n-1)=4\cdot 7\cdot (2q-1)$, i.e. $m=4(2q-1)$.

Hence $[ABC]=4+7m=8(7q-3) \; (q\in\mathbb Z)$,
i.e. $[ABC]=32,88,144,\cdots,984$.

Combining with $(1)$ gives 
$9a=7q-4\; (a\in \mathbb Z)$, which only works for $q=7,16$, giving 
$[ABC]=368\text{ or } 872$.

Comment: are there any quick ways to work through it? or is it kind of a brute force measure

Comment: Probably brute force to some extent. But it helps to reduce the number of possibilities.

Comment: thank you for the more details, was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Say your digits are $a,b,c$. Since it is divisible by 6,7,8,9 must be divisible by 7, 8, 9 (then divisibility by 6 is implied).

- divisibility by 9 implies $7+3+9+a+b+c$ is divisible by 9
- divisibility by 8 implies $100a+10b+c$ is divisible by 8, and also that $c$ is even

Can you derive criterion from divisibility by 7?

Comment: Doesn't divisibility by $8$ rather imply $4a+2b+c \equiv 0 \pmod{8}$?

Comment: @krirkrirk they are equivalent, subtract $96a+8b$...

Comment: yes, I expressed myself poorly. I meant : wouldn't pointing out that $4a+2b+c \equiv 0 \pmod{8}$ be a better hint.

Comment: @krirkrirk agree but want OP himself to do some work :) my way how to constrain mod 7 is more obvious

Comment: once you derive all the equations, how do you solve for a,b, and c

Answer (score 0):

A number is divisible by $6,7,8$ and $9$ if and only if it’s divisible by the least common multiple of $6,7,8$ and $9$, which is $504$. So you need to find those numbers between $739000$ and $739999$ that are divisible by (i.e., integer multiples of) $504$. If you divide $739000$ by $504$, you get a remainder of $136$, so the first multiple of $504$ larger than $739000$ is $504-136 = 368$ greater than $739000$, which is $739368$. And $739368+504=739872$ is the next multiple of $504$ after that and still fits the requirement.